# how to remove substring with and without space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to remove first instances of the word `"hard"` from the given string but I am not sure how to do remove it both with and without spaces:

For example:

`string1 = "it is a hard rock"` needs to become `"it is a rock"`

`string2 = "play hard"` needs to become `"play"`

However, when I use

```py
string1 = string1.replace(hard+ ' ', '', 1)
```

it will not work on `string2` as hard comes at the end without spaces. Any way to deal with this?

Lastly if we have string3

`string3 = "play hard to be hard"` becomes `"play to be hard"`

We want only the first occurrence to be replaced.

Comment: what should happen to `programming is hard, dude`?

Comment: we will keep that kind of "hard," without replacment

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a simple

```
.replace(" hard", "").replace("hard ", "")
```

already works?
If not, I would suggest using a regular expression. But then you would have to give us a few more examples that need to be covered.

Comment: This misses the simlest case of a lone "hard".

Comment: This was not in the original requirements.

The solution doesnt work with example3 now, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a job for some regular expression:

```py
import re

' '.join(filter(bool, re.split(r' *\bhard\b *', 'it is a hard rock', maxsplit=1)))
```

`*` eats up spaces around the word, `\b` guarantees only full words match, `filter(bool, ...)` removes empty strings between consecutive separators (if any) and finally `' '.join` reinstates a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)—

```py
# using if block
" ".join(s.strip() for s in thestring.partition("hard") if s != "hard")

# or with slice notation
" ".join(s.strip() for a in thestring.partition("hard")[::2])
```